# Compile Android Project in Docker Container in Jenkins

Tags: android, docker, ubuntu, jenkins, gradle

I want to compile Android Projects with `Gradle` in Jenkins with Docker and i'm getting following message while building the project:

```
Docker container 9a2b37cfcc86552c0b6635537afd897dbc7639b25394b5f272f402b7d83ed540 started to host the build
[Gradle] - Launching build.
$ docker -H tcp://192.168.0.234:2375 exec --tty 9a2b37cfcc86552c0b6635537afd897dbc7639b25394b5f272f402b7d83ed540 env
Error response from daemon: Container 9a2b37cfcc86552c0b6635537afd897dbc7639b25394b5f272f402b7d83ed540 is not running
ERROR: Build step failed with exception
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to retrieve container's environment
    at com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.docker_build_env.Docker.getEnv(Docker.java:321)
    at com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.docker_build_env.DockerDecoratedLauncher.buildContainerEnvironment(DockerDecoratedLauncher.java:59)
    at com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.docker_build_env.DockerDecoratedLauncher.launch(DockerDecoratedLauncher.java:47)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:455)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.join(Launcher.java:466)
    at hudson.plugins.gradle.Gradle.performTask(Gradle.java:332)
    at hudson.plugins.gradle.Gradle.perform(Gradle.java:224)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:744)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:206)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:163)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:504)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1810)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
Build step 'Invoke Gradle script' marked build as failure
Stopping Docker container after build completion
```

I tried different Dockerfiles like `runmymind/docker-android-sdk` and `thyrlian/android-sdk` - same error.

The OS of the Host-machine is Ubuntu 18 aarch64.

Jenkins Job-Settings:

[image: Docker Plugin]

[image: Gralde Plugin]
[image: Environment Variables]

Comment: I am pretty sure that this is related to that /bin/cat command. That command will exit immediatly, so that when the build step tries to connect to the build container - it is already dead and gone. I am not sure how to configure this though. I think I would go for a Jenkinsfile and a Jenkins pipelines.

Comment: According to the logs, it seems like the communication is not established between Jenkins and the container.  The Docker image `thyrlian/android-sdk` supports SSH connection, so could you please try select **Connect with SSH** in **Connect method**, and mount the `authorized_keys` which contains your Jenkins's public SSH key into the container?  You can find more details here: https://github.com/mytaxi/AndroidCI

Comment: @Hiead Have you got any success in above. please help me in the same scenario. Can you please guilde me to use the docker image of andorid and java for creating the build and testcases. Please check my question once https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68363485/jenkin-server-configuration-for-the-ci-cd-pipeline-to-create-multiple-build-and